# How to set the background color of a cell?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to set the background color of a cell on a excel sheet. I can't get the `XSSFColor` to work. This is what I have so far:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.createCellStyle();
byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
rgb[0] = (byte) 100;
rgb[1] = (byte) 150;
rgb[2] = (byte) 200;
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgb);
style.setFillForegroundColor(color);
```

The line `XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgb);` does not compile:

[image]

How can I create a custom colored `XSSFColor` from RGB or Hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use  `XSSFColor(byte[] rgb, IndexedColorMap colorMap)` constructor to create color instance. You may try to set `colorMap` as `null` here:

```
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgb, null);
```

Or use contructor without parameters and set rgb later:

```
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor();
color.setRGB(rgb);
```

Comment: Is there a way of providing a Hex value, e.g. "#FAFAFA" and get a XSSFColor object ?